# Prism/WPF/C#: ModuleInitializeException When Trying to Run Published ClickOnce Application on other Machines. What Causes this issue?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am working on an application using WPF/Prism/C#. I am publishing the application via ClickOnce using Visual Studios 2015. The application runs fine on the development machine but doesn't open after installation on any other machine.

**From Dev Machine:**

- Win 7 64-bit

I can open the application fine in Visual Studios. Likewise the published ClickOnce version installs and runs fine.

**From other Machines:**

- Win 8 64-bit

Installs seems to succeed but thereafter will crash on startup and closes immediately. When this happens I see the following message in the Windows Event Viewer:

```
Application: FilePlayer.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializeException
Stack:
   at Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.HandleModuleInitializationError(Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo, System.String, System.Exception)
   at Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.Initialize(Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo)
   at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModulesThatAreReadyForLoad()
   at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModuleTypes(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo>)
   at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModulesWhenAvailable()
   at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.Run()
   at Prism.Unity.UnityBootstrapper.InitializeModules()
   at Prism.Unity.UnityBootstrapper.Run(Boolean)
   at Prism.Bootstrapper.Run()
   at FilePlayer.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at FilePlayer.App.Main()

Log Name: Application
Source: .NET RunTime
Task Category: None
Level: Error
Event ID: 1026
```

Can someone provide some guidance on what might be the cause of this issue? Also, how can I attempt to determine the cause/solve this issue?

As I don't know what's the cause I will just provide the project's github: https://github.com/yousefm87/FilePlayer/
If you can help narrow the scope, I can provide relevant code from within the project.

Comment: I downloaded your sample and tried on my machine. I get the same exception. When I navigated into the InnerException property, I found that your `ItemListViewModel` constructor fails with a `DirectoryNotFoundException` for the path 'F:\\ROMS\\SNES Roms'. You have this path in `consoles.json` file. You may not have this folder on all machines you deploy your application to. Are you expecting that folder to exist in all the machines you deploy your application?

Comment: I'm sorry... it seems like my last few commits haven't gone through. I'll fix that and make another comment as confirmation as well as describe how the consoles.json should work (although I made changes for it to be required outside of the application)

Comment: @sthotakura  
The github should now be appropriately trying to get the consoles.json from C:\FPJSON\consoles.json.  
I've posted a guide on what the consoles.json should look like at https://github.com/yousefm87/FilePlayer/wiki/Consoles.Json.  
You should be able to set up the consoles to run vlc with media files instead of emulators/roms if you don't have these.

Comment: Would you create `C:\FPJSON\consoles.json` as part of your application deployment? Otherwise, you will still get that exception, because the application won't be able to find that file on the target machine.

Comment: @sthotakura  
I'm fine with the user needing to provide a C:\FPJSON\consoles.json for now. Did you encounter the Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializeException
 this time around? Also, can you help me determine how to debug this type of issue?

Comment: Yes got the ModuleInitializeException. Your viewmodel trying to find directories mentioned in the consoles.json file, if any of those directories won't exist, your app will crash. You probably need wrap that code in a try-catch block and display a meaningful message to the user about the missing directory. If you give an invalid path in your consoles.json file and try to debug via Visual Studio by pressing F5, you should see this ModuleInitializeException.

Comment: @sthotakura  
When deploying, I add the file C:\FPJSON\consoles.json manually. For now, I expect users to do the same.  
 The file should follow the style described in github.com/yousefm87/FilePlayer/wiki/Consoles.Json Can you please try to run after manually adding a file C:\FPJSON\consoles.json?

Comment: Did you try debugging by having an invalid path in consoles.json to see what the inner exception was when you got ModuleInitializeException?

Comment: No, I'm seeing this issue when I use correct paths.

Comment: Did you debug to see what the inner exception was? - that will give you the actual cause of this ModuleInitializeException.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but it turned out that you were right. It was getting held up because there was a typo in my JSON file. Thank you so much for your help in this matter.